# Using Selenium and Python to push text to Array

Tags: python, arrays, string, unicode, selenium-webdriver

Currently I am using Selenium to scrape a website and it is working nicely up until now. I have Selenium find some text on a page and push it to an Array which will then be output to a CSV file. My problem is in how it is parsing the text it is grabbing.

The code in question is: 
`payload.extend(driver.find_element_by_id("psa_retailPriceDisplay").text)`

The output to the array is:
`['xxxx-1234', u'$', u'3', u'2', u'9', u'.', u'9', u'5']`

And I need it in the format:
`['xxxx-1234','$329.95']`

The first value is already in the array. I have tried encoding it in utf-8 along with a few other things but am not sure how to move forward.

Payload is my current array. I am planning on appending all data to payload.

Comment: `new_list = [output[0], ''.join(output[1:])]`?

Comment: Yes that helps. It is still has the     u prefix however. Thoughts?

Comment: I solved it! Well with your help i needed to wrap it in `str()` !

Comment: are you with Python **2** or Python **3**?

Comment: great, if you don't mind, I may just paste the comment with an actual answer so we can have this question/answer closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
new_list = [str(output[0]), str(''.join(output[1:]))]
```

with `output[0]` keeping the first element in the list, and combine the rest with `join()`, and convert to string using `str()`.